# ArgumentError in Rails::MailersController#preview. Wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My mailer controller never takes the **second argument**. Once I pass in another argument, I get the error as stated in the image below.

**Error**

[image]

**job_notifier.rb**

Note: It works if its only one `job` argument.

```
class JobNotifier < ApplicationMailer

  def send_post_email(job, unsubscribe)
    @user = User.where(:email => true).all
    emails = @user.collect(&:email).join("#{';'}")
    @jobs = job
    @job = job
    @unsubscribe = unsubscribe
    mail(:to => emails, :bcc => User.pluck(:email).uniq, :subject => 'New job posted on FarFlungJobs')
  end

end
```

**mailer trigger**

```
JobNotifier.delay(run_at: 5.minutes.from_now).send_post_email(@job, @unsubscribe)
```

**test/mailer/preview/sjob_notifier_preview.rb**

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/job_notifier
class JobNotifierPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  def send_post_email
    user = User.all
    JobNotifier.send_post_email(user)
  end

end
```

> What could be the problem and how do I fix this?

Comment: The error message states that it is for the preview method in the mailers_controller and you have showed the code for a different controller and method.

Comment: @margo can you expatiate more? Actually don't know what I am missing and where to fix it.

Comment: Can you show the code that triggers the send_post_email method?

Comment: @margo see the update. Thats what I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

In the job_notifier_preview

```
JobNotifier.send_post_email(user)
```

only sends one parameter. Are you sure you are sending the correct parameters? You need to pass it 2 parameters.